# Grails Nested Eager Query Using Fetch

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have following domain setup

```
class Classified{
   static belongsTo = [item: Item]
}

class Item{
   static hasMany = [images: Image, classifieds: Classified]
}

class Image{
   static belongsTo = [item: Item]
}
```

I would like to create a list view where I would display all the classified along with its item name and corresponding image. This needs to be done in least number of database queries.

in my controller, I have following code

```
params.fetch = [item:'join']
def query = Classified.where {item.user == user}
respond query.list(params), model:[classifiedInstanceCount: query.count()]
```

this codes does as expected which is to eager load the item. I would like to eager load the images as well. I have tried several variations but couldn't get it to work.

```
params.fetch = [item:'join', 'item.image':'join']
params.fetch = [item:[image:'join']]
```

Any help is appreciated to help figure out how to do nested join with fetch.
I know about the alternatives to use criteria builder, hibernate query and declaring "lazy: false" in the domain class. I want to how to get nested query working using "fetch".

Thank you.